# Plotting the mean over a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a mean line over this bar chart.

[image]

my current code is as follows

```
chart_1 = agg_df[['Home Points %','Away Points %']].plot(kind='bar', title =" Home Points V Away Points", 
                                                figsize=(10, 6), legend=True, fontsize=12)
chart_1.set_xlabel("Season", fontsize=14)
chart_1.set_ylabel("Percentage of Points", fontsize=14)



plt.show()
```

Does anyone have any tips on how I will go about adding a horizontal line for both the home mean and the away mean?

Comment: [`Axes.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html)?

Comment: How would I go about applying that would I need to set the mean as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from seaborn import load_dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_tips = load_dataset('tips')
df_means = df_tips.groupby(['day', 'sex'])['tip'].mean().to_frame()

ax = df_means.unstack()['tip'].plot.bar(legend=False)
ax.hlines(df_means['tip'].mean(level=0),[-.25, .75, 1.75, 2.75], np.arange(.25,4))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
import numpy as np
chart1.axhline(np.mean(agg_df["Away Points"]), color="orange")
chart1.axhline(np.mean(agg_df["Home Points"]), color="blue")
```

Note: Untested code, since I could not replicate your exact dataframe.